# Cannot get sensor to connect using gpio: problem with i2c

Tags: gpio, i2c, sensor

I'm following [this guide for a temperature sensor programme](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/#step-ten) and I'm not getting very far with it, at step 3A I seem to have issues finding the sensor. When I enter `cd /sys/bus/w1/devices/` followed by the `ls` as instructed I get nothing at all, just `pi@raspberrypi /sys/bus...` again on the next command line.

I then took a look around and [working through the various steps on this site](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-I2C-Python/step2/Enable-I2C/) I still find myself nowhere closer to getting the thing working. Step 2, the blacklist file was empty. Step 3, file includes the required lines now. Step 4, `i2c tools already at the newest version`
and `user pi already a member of i2c`.

`i2cdetect -y 1` will display:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
 00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

even when the gpio pins are connected to the circuit with the sensor.
`i2cdetect -y 0` or other numbers will show `error: could not open file /dev/i2c/-0: no such file or dictionary`

Note, I am using Jessie, the update step in the first link says wheezy, I followed it replacing Wheezy for Jessie, same results as above, then changed it to follow the guide exactly (using Wheezy), same as above.

Note also that if I type `sudo raspi-config`, go to advanced options, there is no options to enable/disable the i2c or spi, advanced options contains only 6 options, Expand file system, overscan, memory split, audio, resolution, gl driver.

Edit:
TSIC 306 TO92 is the model number,  IST 15 T01C is printed on the actual sensor itself.

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1792637.pdf?_ga=1.191625965.631748920.1487716453 I'm using the 3 pin one.

Comment: Model number is TSIC 306 TO92, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TSIC 306 uses a protocol called digital ZACWire.

It is not compatible with the I2C bus or the Dallas 1-wire bus protocols.

Have a look at this raspberrypi.org forum thread.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=30325&p=526369

It appears that someone got it to work with my pigpio library.